# C# Unit Testing Lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test in visual studios 2013,I know that using the method below with the supplied parameters will return a list containing the content of "Search term empty or contains invalid characters, please try again".

My method is

```
public List<string> SearchAnagram(string searchTerm,int userid)
    {  
        List<string> matchedAnagrams = new List<string>();

        matchedAnagrams.Add("Search term empty or contains invalid characters, please try again");      

        return matchedAnagrams;     
    }
```

test method below:

```
public void TestDigitSearchTerm()
    {
        List<string> matchedAnagrams = new List<string>();
        matchedAnagrams.Add("Search term empty or contains invalid characters, please try again");
        Assert.AreEqual(matchedAnagrams, anagram.SearchAnagram("gd32", 1));
    }
```

However what I receive is

```
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]>.
Actual:  <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]>.
```

From what I can see they are they exact same so the test should of worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [CollectionAssert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx):

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(matchedAnagrams, anagram.SearchAnagram("gd32", 1))
```

Or

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(matchedAnagrams, anagram.SearchAnagram("gd32", 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great, didn't realise there was another assert, gotta wait a few mins to mark as answer though.

Comment: Or, assert that `SeuquenceEqual` https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your visual studio is configured with the correct Target Framework. Double click on the project it will open the following window
[Preference window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPBGe.png)

Click on General option, select an installed target framework from the drop down and re-run your tests

[Target Framework selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZkS7.png)